# mediaelement.js WordPress Plugin getting parse error

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've been using the media element js Wordpress plugin version 2.1.7 on my Wordpress site for MP3 audio playback. I'm up to date with Wordpress running 3.2.1. The audio player is getting stuck on "loading" and if you check the JS error logs it's reporting a "parse error". You can see an example here:

http://www.maccast.com/2011/08/19/maccast-2011-08-19/

I'm using the short code:

```
[audio src="http://www.maccast.com/media/MC20110819.mp3" type="audio/mp3"]
```

The code reporting the parse error is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer({
        m:1
       ,features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','tracks','fullscreen']
    ,audioWidth:,audioHeight:
    });
});
</script>
```

And the error is:

```
/2011/08/19/maccast-2011-08-19/:355SyntaxError: Parse error
```

I assume the permalink path that precedes "SyntaxError: Parse error" is just part of the standard error reporting in Safari, or could that be part of the parsing problem?